# php XMLwriter file size limit

Tags: php, xml, xmlwriter

I'm creating an xml file from an sql query using PHP.
If the query returns more than about 500 records, the xml file is not written fully and I get an error message from the PHP server saying:

"The server is temporarily unable to service your
request due to maintenance downtime or capacity
problems."

I'm not sure if I am doing this correctly or not. I can do the same thing in VB without a problem. The finished sql query should have around 5000 records and be about 4mb in size.

Here is the code I am using:

```
$writer = new XMLWriter();
$writer->openUri('mydoc.xml');
$writer->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$writer->setIndent(4);
$writer->startElement('FE_Time');  //create root element

while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($db->result)){ 

  //I load data from the oracle query into variables and use them below:

     $writer->startElement('Item'); //create item element
         $writer->writeElement("Plate_No", $Plate_No);
         $writer->writeElement("Job_No", $Job_No);
         $writer->writeElement("Hold_Time", $Hold_Time);
         $writer->writeElement("OE_Time", $OE_Time);
         $writer->writeElement("Ship_Date", $Ship_Date);
     $writer->endElement(); //end the Item Element
}

$writer->endElement(); //end the FE_Time root element
$writer->endDocument(); //close the document
$writer->flush();  //clear the memory

unset($db); //close db connection
```

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated, I"m thinking there must be a limit to how many records xmlWriter can handle?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you give:

> "The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems."

Is not a specific error message of PHP but from your webserver. Enable PHP error logging, locate the error log and find the exact error that describes what happens with more detail.

So far for the troubleshooting.

The generic error message hints that you've run out of resources with your script. This can be that your script crashed, has run out of memory or has run out of time (I can only guess and not better say as the PHP Error is missing, so this just for a general direction).

One potential thing you could do is to move the flush

```
$writer->flush();  //clear the memory
```

into the `while` loop so that the file is written to disk for each `$row`:

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($db->result)) {

    ...

    $writer->endElement(); //end the Item Element
    $writer->flush();
    #################
}
```

Also

```
$writer->endDocument();
```

will flush XMLWriter as well, so you do not need to call it one line before that method call.

Hope this helps you to get things runnning.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm going to implement what you have suggested. After some testing, it turns out that it is my oracle query that the web server can't handle. It seems to time out. How do I enable PHP error logging to see what's happening?

Comment: One thing that helped me was making sure that `header('Content-type: text/xml');` is placed at the top of the script